# Postgres's query to select value in array by index

Tags: r, postgresql

My data is string like:

```
'湯姆 is a boy.' 

or '梅isagirl.' 

or '約翰,is,a,boy.'.
```

And I want to split the string and only choose the Chinese name.

In R, I can use the command

```
tmp=strsplit(string,[A-z% ])

unlist(lapply(tmp,function(x)x[1]))
```

And then getting the Chinese name I want.

But in PostgreSQL

```
select regexp_split_to_array(string,'[A-z% ]') from db.table
```

I get a array like {'湯姆','','',''},{'梅','','',''},...
And I don't know how to choose the item in the array.

I try to use the command

```
select regexp_split_to_array(string,'[A-z% ]')[1] from db.table
```

and I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `regexp_split_to_array` is the appropriate function for what you are trying to do here.  Instead, use `regexp_replace` to selectively remove all ASCII characters:

```
SELECT string, regexp_replace(string, '[[:ascii:]~:;,"]+', '', 'g') AS name
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that you might have to adjust the set of characters to be removed, depending on what other non Chinese characters you expect to have in the `string` column.  This answer gives you a general suggestion for how you might proceed here.

Comment: There are many other symbols in my strings like '-','::','~',.... So that I want to split the strings and then choose the first one.

Comment: I got the idea of using 'match'. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @錢冠邑 Then add them to the character class.